# ASP.NET MVC 4, Entity Framework 5 database-first role management and membership integration in same database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework. I searched for this on google but I didn't get it may be it is my fault.

I am creating new application using previous database. I want to create user account with different roles and access

I want to use same structure for role management which is generated by ASP.NET MVC 4, but it generates different database for that, I don't want in different database, I want to include in same/my database.

Please anyone answer me how to integrate that structure in my database so that I can use same functionality through my database or it is possible to do in database first?

Please help me I am working on it from last 4 days.

Comment: Have you read [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) ?

Comment: keep the connection-string same for asp.net membership and your main database

Comment: Thanks Ankush,I tried that but it shows error